# Designing image gallery in CSS

Tags: css

I am new to this. I want to design an image gallery in my webpage. Currently iam using bluprint CSS framework for my web. Can anyone suggest me a better way to design a image gallery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at this from [dynamicdrive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-image-gallery/)

the [hoverbox](http://sonspring.com/journal/hoverbox-image-gallery).

[A very nice plug-in for jQuery](http://fancy.klade.lv/).

Comment: To everyone who sees the post: the link removed was dead and therefore removed - there's an archive of it in web archive - see the revision history and specifically revision's 3 summary!

Answer (score 0):

Blueprint CSS will be fine. You'll need to get your hands dirty though, Blueprint won't do all the work in designing a gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already had a look at the [Wikipedia comparison of Photo Gallery software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_gallery_software) for a nice list of similar software packages. I personally made good experiences with [4images](http://www.4homepages.de).

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Use [Lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) as a JQuery plugin!